# How to style links on a resume/CV?

Tags: color, resume

What is the best way to style a link on one's resume/CV? Let's assume this styling doesn't cross over to a printed page and focus solely on the PDF. Should links be underlined and colored blue (like most of the web)? I've experimented with a few different options, and I think color coding + underlining works as long as coloring(blue) and underlining aren't used for any other purpose elsewhere in the resume.

The most important thing I want people to get as soon as they see my resume is that they can click on links to my website, LinkedIn, GitHub, to send me an email, or go to websites for my projects (reduces the need for them to copy/paste). And of course, I also want it to look good. I'd be curious to hear what you have done?

Answer (score 4):

Most often for non-interactive content (printed) where the url is in the middle of other same-sized text, I merely underline.

I do *not* underline large promotional URLS, only URls in the middle of similar text.

[image]

If additional emphasis on mid-paragraph URLs is desired, I'll use boldface:

[image]

I do not ever color links specifically, unless the client ask for it, or it's purposefully done for emphasis, and in that case, blue isn't seen as mandatory to me.

i.e. ...

[image]

---

The *only* time I'll use both an underline and *specifically* blue.. is in promotional **emails**.. where the "click elements" need to be visually prominent and as intuitive as possible.

---

This is merely ***opinion*** and how I tend to handle URLS.